# Android: After updating Android Studio tu 0.8.7 Gradle error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After updating Android Studio to 0.8.7 my Gradle wont sync.
I use local distribution of gradle 2.0 which Android studio downloaded. In settings I have set url to use that local distribution from .gradle.

Here's my build.gradle and below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0'
  }
}


 Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0/gradle-2.0.pom
    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0/gradle-2.0.jar
 Required by:
    :App:unspecified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the Gradle Android plugin (`com.android.tools.build:gradle`) is 0.11.1, and it supports Gradle 1.10-1.12 (see [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Requirements)).

Comment: Peter, as suggestion "you can keep gradle 2.0 installed but use ./gradlew which is wired to 1.12 gradle (how to configure http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)". But probably for someone is easier to downgrade gradle version especially if they don't need gralde 2.0

Comment: actually the latest version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` is `0.12.2`

Comment: It got this from the docs; apparently they are outdated then (still say 0.11.1).